# Matlab: how to use numeric arrays such as 1:2 to create a cell array such as {1,2}?

Tags: matlab, types, cell-array

I want to use the numeric array such as 1:7 to create a cell array such as `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`. How can I do it? By which function?

**Wrong**

```
>> {1:2}

ans = 

    [1x2 double]
```

**Correct output**

```
>> {1,2}

ans = 

    [1]    [2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
num2cell(1:7)
```

which converts every number to a single element in the output cell.

There are more things you can do with it; type `help num2cell` for more info.

There's a bunch of alternative approaches, the easiest I think would be

```
arrayfun(@(x)x, 1:7, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

or the good old `for` loop:

```
N = 7;

C = cell(N,1);
for ii = 1:N
    C{ii} = ii; end
```

Despite what you hear about `for` loops in MATLAB, they are not so terrible anymore. If you repeat Nick's test for larger N, you'll see that `num2cell` is fastest, then the `for` loop, and then `arrayfun`.

Comment: :) That's just steeling part of my answer :(

Comment: @Nick: euhmmm...I was first :)

Comment: True... but not for the `arrayfun` part... but you have a good point about arrayfun :) So +1

Comment: @Nick: well, since we both thought of the same thing at the same time, +1 for you too :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Do you have more specific info on "`for` loops in MATLAB, they are not so terrible anymore"? That's interesting

Answer (score 2):

n my view there are two ways to do this. `num2cell` is by far the best method, but I'd like to mention the `arrayfun` method as well.

```
>> arrayfun(@(a)(a), 1:7, 'UniformOutput', false);


>> num2cell(1:7);
```

Comment: Note that if you increase the size to say, `1:1e6`, it is `num2cell` that clearly wins.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I agree... but the `tic` `toc` is not the main reason I have mentioned it. But I have removed it now. Arrayfun can be a very useful function throughout Matlab. It seems that hhh is learning matlab. So let's help him as much as possible. :)